# How to filter based on postgres ARRAY type length in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to filter the db to get result based on the array column's length. In specific I need to get results which are of length <= given value.

For Example:

```
| COLNAME     |
+-------------+
| {1}         |
| {3,20,3400} |
| {1,4,7}     |
| {3,3279}    |
| {1,4}       |
| {3}         |
| {1,4,54}    |
| {3,44}      |
| {}          |
```

And I need to get let's say length <= 2 and expected result would be:

```
| COLNAME  |
+----------+
| {1}      |
| {3,3279} |
| {1,4}    |
| {3}      |
| {3,44}   |
| {}       |
```

I'm new to this, so I'm not able to find it on my own properly. `array_agg` and `array_length or cardinality (array_length gives null for empty array, I would prefer 0, which cardinality is giving)` functions are there which might help, I'm looking into how to use it properly, but if someone just knows that will be a big help.

I have managed to write the raw sql query, just need some help converting to sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *, cardinality(COLNAME) AS X FROM tablename) as mod
WHERE X <= 2;
```

Edit:
I guess the issue is mostly that I don't understand how to use sqlalchemy properly, I have just used `db.engine.execute('SQL statements').fetchall()` for now, I'll post the answer when I'm good enough.

Comment: You should be able to use `func.cardinality()` in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it is simpler than I thought.

```
res = obj.query.filter(func.cardinality(obj.colname) <= val).all()
```